# How to change tsconfig.json inside NX Vite library/app builds

Tags: monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl, nx-monorepo

Have someone found a way to customise the tsconfig.json for NX project build. When using Vite as bundler?

Here is the problem below is a standart NX(18.0.4) vite.config.ts for library. When you do 'nx build libd' NX is consuming the vite.config.ts bellow and builds your code. The problem is that `nxViteTsPaths()` is the place where the tscofig.json is selected by NX but it does not allow any customisation and always fallback to the [root]/tsconfig.base.json, so is there a way to force NX to use any other then [root]/tsconfig.base.json for building your vite library?

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';
import * as path from 'path';
import { nxViteTsPaths } from '@nx/vite/plugins/nx-tsconfig-paths.plugin';

export default defineConfig({
  root: __dirname,
  cacheDir: '../../node_modules/.vite/packages/libd',

  plugins: [
    react(),
    nxViteTsPaths(),
    dts({
      entryRoot: 'src',
      tsConfigFilePath: path.join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.lib.json'),
      skipDiagnostics: true,
    }),
  ],

  // Uncomment this if you are using workers.
  // worker: {
  //  plugins: [ nxViteTsPaths() ],
  // },

  // Configuration for building your library.
  // See: https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode
  build: {
    outDir: '../../dist/packages/libd',
    reportCompressedSize: true,
    commonjsOptions: {
      transformMixedEsModules: true,
    },
    lib: {
      // Could also be a dictionary or array of multiple entry points.
      entry: 'src/index.ts',
      name: 'libd',
      fileName: 'index',
      // Change this to the formats you want to support.
      // Don't forget to update your package.json as well.
      formats: ['es', 'cjs'],
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // External packages that should not be bundled into your library.
      external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react/jsx-runtime'],
    },
  },

  test: {
    globals: true,
    cache: {
      dir: '../../node_modules/.vitest',
    },
    environment: 'jsdom',
    include: ['src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,mjs,cjs,ts,mts,cts,jsx,tsx}'],

    reporters: ['default'],
    coverage: {
      reportsDirectory: '../../coverage/packages/libd',
      provider: 'v8',
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: I removed `nxViteTsPaths()` from plugins list and now it is taking project level tsconfig. This works for me for `package based libs`. Let me know if this works for you.